# Collecting Multiple Column Values on a Variable Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to set the value of a range of columns on one sheet to the value of a range of columns on another sheet. I don't want to copy the entire row I only want to target specific columns as to not potentially overwrite important information inside the other cells.

Currently my code starts at the top of Sheet 1 and loops to the bottom. With each value > 0 in column 4 it searches for the identical value in column 4 of Sheet 2. If a match is found I want to copy the values from column 10-13 on x row of Sheet 1 to column 10-13 on y row of Sheet 2.

I can make this work by matching the value in each column individually but I cannot seem to find the proper method for assigning the value for a range of columns. The first line of code is what I have that currently works. The second line is what I am attempting to copy a range of column values.

```
ws2.Cells(y, 4).Value = ws1.Cells(x, 4).Value
ws2.Range(y, 10:13).Value = ws1.Range(x, 10:13).Value
```

I have tried using the Union() method but perhaps I am not sure how to implement it in this situation. Below is the rest of my code.

```
Sub Upload()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws1LastRow As Long, ws2LastRow As Long
Dim ws1Row As Long, ws2Row As Long
Dim FindRow2 As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("Sheet Address")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Master")

ws1LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ws2LastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For ws1Row = 2 To ws1LastRow

    Do While ws1.Cells(ws1Row, 4) <> ""

        ws2.Range("D:D").Find(What:=ws1.Cells(ws1Row, 4).Text, _
        LookIn:=xlValues).Select

        r = ActiveCell.Row  

        ws2.Cells(r, "B").Value = ws1.Cells(ws1Row, "B").Value

        ws1Row = ws1Row + 1

    Loop   

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why you are executing double loop through `ws1Row` first with `For` and second with `Do`.  I think instead of `Do loop` it will be 'If  ws1.Cells(ws1Row, 4) <> "" then` and like.

Comment: Please only input productive comments. Saying "this is a bad idea" and not offering a solution is in no way helpful.

Comment: First comment the variable ws1Row is not defined anywhere in the code before then so that is why the For loop is included. Is it best practice? Probably not. Your solution will not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### `Range.Resize(Rows, Columns)`

---

```
ws2.Range("J" & y).Resize(, 3).Value = ws1.Range("J" & x).Resize(, 3).Value
```

Comment: Some feedback on the downvote would be appreciated as this answers the question

Comment: Works great. You are my hero and also the only one who left a productive comment. Thank you very much for your feedback.